# I am creating WordPress Upload media meta box but its never showing my image in the filed

Tags: wordpress

Currently I am working with media upload button to insert my image url in that particular filed so that I can use that in my page and post accordingly. Here is my code which I am using right now:

```
<div class="custom-meta-box">
   <label for="upload_image">Upload Background Image for header section</label>
   <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image" value="" />
   <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
</div>
```

To show front end, it works fine and it shows up that nice button and field.
Then:

```
function my_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');

    wp_enqueue_script('my-upload', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js', 'jquery', null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');
}

function my_admin_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}

// better use get_current_screen(); or the global $current_screen
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page'){

    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');
    add_action('admin_enqueue_styles', 'my_admin_styles');
}
```

Until now, every thing works fine rest of the code is:

```
// better use get_current_screen(); or the global $current_screen
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page'){

    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');
    add_action('admin_enqueue_styles', 'my_admin_styles');
}
```

Here is my js code as well.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {
    alert('hi kami');
    $('#upload_image_button').click(function() {

        formfield = $('#upload_image').attr('name');
        tb_show( '', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true' );
        return false;
    });

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {

        imgurl = $('img',html).attr('src');
        $('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
    }

});
```

And once I click on the upload Image button it shows that up-loader screen fine, but as soon as I click on Insert Image into post button, it never shows image link into my input field means never inserts my image. Any body there to figure out where am I going wrong ???

Comment: Alert (or console log) imgurl in the window.send_to_editor function and see if you are actually getting something, If not do the same with the html and see if that is returning anything. I had to tweak something similar myself to get a proper url returning.

Comment: okay let me check that as well

Comment: I have alerted that imgurl variable and it says undefined :( ... on the other hand i alerted html it shows full image with src and sizes as well ... , now how to get that img src from that html .. any one guide me plzzz

Comment: I will give what I use - its not great so won't put it as an actual answer but might work for you.... `imgurl = html.split('"'); imgurl = imgurl[1].replace('<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>','');` use those instead of your existing imgurl = line

Comment: Let me know if that was any use to you @laraib

Comment: No, that was not of any issue solution for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your code inside `div` tag and that will solve your issue. Make your line like this:

```
imgurl = $("<div>" + html + "</div>").find("img").attr("src");
```

Rest will work fine for you ... hope that solves your problem as it solved mine a time ago now